# DocuSign eSignature REST API v2.1 Java : Document in html format with non English language

Tags: docusignapi

I am using eSignature REST API v2.1 Java to create envelope. Document is in html format with non English language. On the signing page these non English is not displayed properly. How to handle this case? Thanks,

`String htmlDoc = ".... .... <p>Signera arbetsorderavtal för anställningsnummer</p> ......";`

`Document document = new Document();`

`document.setDocumentId("1");`

`document.setName("name");`

`document.setDocumentBase64(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(htmlDoc));`

`document.setFileExtension("html");`

`envelopeDefinition.setDocuments(Arrays.asList(document));`

Output:
[image]

Expecting proper display of the foreign language.

Answer (score 1):

My code is:

```
String htmlDoc = "<p>Signera arbetsorderavtal för anställningsnummer</p>"; // removed <html> & <body>
byte[] byteArray = htmlDoc.getBytes(**StandardCharsets.UTF_8**);

Document document = new Document();
document.setDocumentId("1");
document.setName("name");
document.setFileExtension("html");
document.setDocumentBase64(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArray));
```

Output:
[Signing Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaVb3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling Java that the string is Unicode Transformation Format or UTF-8.
Here is your code fixed:

```
String htmlDoc = ".... .... <p>Signera arbetsorderavtal för anställningsnummer</p> ......";

Document document = new Document();

document.setDocumentId("1");

document.setName("name");

document.setDocumentBase64(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(htmlDoc.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

document.setFileExtension("html");

envelopeDefinition.setDocuments(Arrays.asList(document));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, I actually have it in my code, just missed it here.

Comment: I just tied this code with the exact string you put with the unicode characters (Signera arbetsorderavtal för anställningsnummer) and it works just fine, I see them correctly in DocuSign

Comment: (but if I didn't have the StandardCharsets.UTF_8 then I see the issue you see

Comment: My test html content is something like this `"<html><body><div>Signera arbetsorderavtal för anställningsnummer</div><div><span style="color:white;">{{ANCHOR_SIGNATURE_1}}</span></div></body></html>"`. This is not producing the proper pdf output.

Comment: ok, just to try to understand this problem, if you just do a <p></p> with the Swedish text, does this work? I'm trying to figure out where is the problem, is it with the rest of the HTML, the encoding  or what/?

Comment: Yes, just `<p></p>` with Swedish text works. However the `<p>` & `</p>` tags show up on the pdf. When <html> tag is present, the output is not rendered properly. My requirement is to dynamically create work order document for signing in 10+ languages.

Comment: hmmm, that is odd, it didn't do this for me, it just showed the text, no <p> tags show

Comment: Can you please update the answer with the exact code and what you see? I don't see the <p> in your screenshot and the code is missing the StandardCharsets.UTF_8 so I'm not sure how to help and what is the issue

Comment: Any account level settings related to this?

Comment: Depends what you are trying to use. Maybe you are using something called smart sections?

Comment: Are you using responsive signing? https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/creating-signable-html/

Comment: I am not using responsive signing. (not setting htmlDefinition())

Comment: then as long as extension is set to "html" - it should be treated as HTML and you should not see <p> in there unless it's invalid HTML